# Why with scala, using the same regular expression, using 2 different matching methods lead to 2 different results?

Tags: regex, scala

Why there is a match here:

```
scala> """\bdog\b""".r
res65: scala.util.matching.Regex = \bdog\b
scala> res65.findFirstIn(" The dog plays in the yard")
res66: Option[String] = Some(dog)
```

But not here:

```
scala> "The dog plays in the yard".matches("""\bdog\b""")
res67: Boolean = false
```

?

Comment: *Not* a stupid question. In .NET for example, `Regex.IsMatch()` also finds substrings. In Python `re.match()` only anchors the search at the start but not the end of the string. Regular expressions are confusing on their own, but the different implementations vary wildly enough to make a grown man cry (unless he's got RegexBuddy, of course).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second case, the whole stirng has to match the regex, in the first case, any part of the string can match. Compare the second case to this:

```
"The dog plays in the yard".matches(""".*\bdog\b.*""")
```

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing `findFirstIn` with `matches`, and of course the string *contains*, but doesn't *match* `\bdog\b`.

Comment: Then again, that definition of "match" is not the _usual_ definition of match, as defined by libregex, sed, awk, perl, etc.